# kendo Grid excelExport's hideColumn not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendospreadsheet

I am trying to hide one column from excelExport. I have tried some traditional ways shown on google like `e.sender.hideColumn(13)` or `e.sender.hideColumn("bID")` or `grid.hideColumn(13)`. but none of this working for me. I have also done exportPDF which is working perfectly.

here is JS code I am attaching, to show what I am doing.

```
$("#ALReport").kendoGrid({
        toolbar: ["excel", "pdf"],
        excel: {
            allPages: true,
            fileName: "ALReport" + todayDateFormatted() + ".xlsx",
            proxyURL: "/content",
            filterable: true
        },
        excelExport: function (e) {
            e.sender.hideColumn(12);
            var grid = $("#ALReport").data("kendoGrid");
            grid.hideColumn("Bid");
        },
        pdf: {
            allPages: true,
            filterable: true,
            fileName: "ALReport" + todayDateFormatted() + ".pdf",
            proxyURL: "/content",
            margin: {
                left: 10,
                right: "10pt",
                top: "10mm",
                bottom: "1in"
            }
        },
        pdfExport: function (e) {
            var grid = $("#ALReport").data("kendoGrid");
            grid.hideColumn("Bid");
            $(".k-grid-toolbar").hide();
            e.promise
           .done(function () {
               grid.showColumn("Bid");
               $(".k-grid-toolbar").show();
           });
        },
        dataSource: {
            serverSorting: true,
            serverPaging: true,
            transport: {
                read: getActionURL() + "ALReport....
            },

.....
```

This is my js code. Can anyone guide where i am making mistake?

Comment: pdfExport is working as expected, i have tried to putting that code in excel but no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your export to excel has no effect because event is fired after all data have been collected. For your example try following approach:

```
var exportFlag = false;
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
         toolbar: ["excel", "pdf"],
         excel: {
          allPages: true,
          fileName: "ALReport" + todayDateFormatted() + ".xlsx",
          proxyURL: "/content",
          filterable: true
        },
       excelExport: function (e) {
        if (!exportFlag) {
          e.sender.hideColumn("Bid");
          e.preventDefault();
          exportFlag = true;
          setTimeout(function () {
              e.sender.saveAsExcel();
          });
      } else {
          e.sender.showColumn("Bid");
          exportFlag = false;
      }
    }
```

For this example event is prevented and fired one more time excluding hidden column.

Comment: oh ... magic ... working ... but i am not getting why its needed

Comment: When excelExport is fired, all data required for export is already agregated. So just hideColumn will not have any effect. Looks like pdf export logic is different and column collection can be modified during event execution.